# Multiple opacity transitions using callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, opacity, fadeto

I am trying to create an image transition aka slideshow, like they have on:
www.teamgeek.co.za/ - the first image on the left you see!, it works by just having a script which changes the opacity of the images.

I have started to try and make something like this, here is my progress:
http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/1/

```
$( "#change" ).click(function() {
    $( "#image1" ).fadeTo( "slow" , 0, function() {
        $("#image2").fadeTo("slow" , 1, function(){
            $("#image3").fadeTo("slow", 1, function(){
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Now my problem is that, I need the transition to be slower then "slow", because it just doesn't feel as slow and "correct" as the one seen on teamgeek's site.

Comment: you can define the time in milliseconds, https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: can you add example please?

Comment: see the jquery doc for examples and explanations

Comment: Okay cool, don't give me an example then, nice job mate.

Comment: the time it took you to write out the question and read/reply to my comment. You could of easily google the jquery doc and read it. I don't like to promote laziness. research is important for devs

Comment: Clearly ive been trying to do it by reading the docs, but failed, which is why im here, why would I find it usefull for someone to send me a link to something again,

Comment: How did you fail by reading the doc? the example is right there

Comment: it doesn't matter, its because the one I was reading didn't deal with parameters in milliseconds, and you edited that link in after, so I didn't see It at first, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slower than slow - http://jsfiddle.net/pYECC/2/

```
$("#change").click(function() {
    $("#image1").fadeTo(5000 , 0, function() {
        $("#image2").fadeTo(5000 , 1, function(){
            $("#image3").fadeTo(5000, 1, function(){
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!, do you know how I would make it loop? so it keeps transitioning from start to end? thanks

Comment: Yes but for that you would have to ask another question. Thats how this website works my friend.